# How can one type decorators to correctly infer types?

Tags: typescript, this, decorator, type-inference, union-types

Basically I have this function:

```
function portable(func) {
    return function(...args) {
        if (typeof this === undefined) {
            return func(...args)
        } else {
            return func(this, ...args)
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to add types to it, such that the type of this function:

```
const add = portable((x: number, y: number): number => x + y)
```

Can be correctly inferred as the union of these two types:

```
(this: undefined, x: number, y: number) => number
(this: number, y: number) => number
```

Is what I'm asking possible within the type system? And if so could anyone give a way of expressing such a type?

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does. `func` will always be called with `this` set to `undefined`.

Comment: See [the generated JavaScript on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20portable(func)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function(...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20func(...args)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20func(this%2C%20...args)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20add%20%3D%20portable((x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%20y)%3B%0A)

Comment: Why do you want a union? an overloaded declaration seems more ergonomic.

Comment: What's the difference between an overload and a union? Like isn't the type of this `(x) => typeof x === 'number' ? x : 'foo'` essentially just a union of `(x: number) => number` and `(x: any) => string`?

Comment: Mike that's the idea, the decorated func doesn't use this, but the function returned by the decorator does, the type I was referring to was the type of the decorated func but `(x: number, y: number) => number` is the type of the undecorated function, but the returned function from portable can have a non-undefined this if I attach it to an object and call it as a method.

Comment: So an equivalent question that would allow me to solve it would be how can I mirror the type of a function's arguments and extend it e.g. could I extract the type from any given function and inject an argument, if so I could probably solve the rest of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this to currently to be impossible based on a couple hours research where I discovered [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453).

Effectively it doesn't seem to be possible to capture the type of function parameters even if the parameters are known, effectively I can't represent this in any conceivable way:

```
function addUselessArg(func) {
    return function(first: 'Banana', ...args) {
        return func(...args)
    }
}
```

It's obvious that the type of `addUselessArg((x: number) => x**2)` is `(first: 'Banana', x: number) => number` but there's no way that seems to be possible without be able to specify the type of variadic parameter `args` to be the type of `func`'s arguments.